# Looking to remove the value of google pie chart on hover

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
    data.addRows([
      ['Male', 51],
      ['Female', 49],
    ]);

    // Set options for Sarah's pie chart.
    var options = {title:"",
                   width:600,
                   height:400,
                   is3D: true};
```

Above is my code. I'm looking to remove the value on the hover but keep the percentages in the pie chart. So on my chart it says Male: 51(51%) Female: 49(49%). It won't let me attach a picture since I'm fairly new so I apologize for that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add one more configuration **tooltip** in options object:

```
var options = {
    title:"",
    width:600,
    height:400,
    tooltip: {
        text: 'percentage'
    },
    is3D: true
};
```

Here is demo : https://jsfiddle.net/fs6tc5nq/1/